# How to add an image as pre-loader in a Flash CS4 file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a flash file (.fla) which is created in Adobe Flash CS4.

I want to add pre-loader which is basically a simple .gif image (my company logo). I want when someone run that flash (.swf) file, first for at least 3 seconds my company logo will be displayed and then the rest flash file will execute.

I am new to Flash CS4, so can anyone guide me step-by-step how to add a pre-loader image?

Comment: what is in the rest of the flash file? what are you publishing the file as?

Comment: @Josh, I am publishing it as .swf (using ctrl+enter). Rest of teh file contains some presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a splash screen, not a preloader.

Just put the picture in the first keyframe, and then have the rest of the site appear in a later keyframe. You can read about frames and keyframes here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7ec8a.html

In any case, flash will display the first frame before the whole file is loaded, so it will kinda act like a preloader. Except if you have lots of classes "exported" in frame 1, but if you are new to flash you problerly do not ;)